# Competing risks / survival analysis R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Another question on dealing with competing risks in R,

I have to analyse the survival function until the event "metastases or death" with or without taking into account the competing risk "local recurrence", in two different groups of treatment. 
I have for this: 
The variable vectors for status
status_meta: 1 if metastases at time "t" 0 if else
status_death: 1 if death at time "t" 0 if else
status_loc: 1 if  local recurrence at time "t" 0 if else

The variable vectors for time till event: 
time_meta, 
time_death, 
time_loc

I need to merge the vectors of the status (or the times) so I could have only one vector for the status: 1 for metastases OR death, 2 for local recurrence and 0 if else (non informative censoring present in each of the three baseline vectors)
I think it could be possible with apply() and which.min but I didn't know how to use it (with times or with status?)
I tried this:

```
data$etat_comp<-apply(cbind(data$time_meta,data$time_death,data$time_loc),1,
which.min)-1
```

But I have this message error

```
Error in apply(cbind(data$time_meta, data$time_death, data$time_loc), 1,  : 
non numeric argument for binary operator
```

I tried also to na.omit for the cbind but doesn't work neither

I also need to fix the times vectors so I will have a vector for time until mestatse OR death and another vector for time until local recurrence.

These steps are necessary because I had to choose which status (meta Or death) considering the main event with taking into account the competing risk (local recurrence) in Fine and Grey or Cox ph regression.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO! I do not think your question is emperical and requires more focus, and you have not asked a question, you just described an exercise.
Please read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Also try it for yourself first and then ask here.

Comment: Local recurrence is not really a competing risk. It would certainly modify the risk of subsequent metastasis. The two types of events are quite different. Local recurrence has little impact on immediate death  risk. dDeath without metastasis would be “competitive” with death following metastasis.

Comment: We preferred a composite failure death+metastases and we want to see if the theoretical risk of failure (metastases+death) is influenced by local recurrence (the risk set could change its risk because taking into account local recurrences, not censoring them with Fine and Gray model) (the treatment change if local recurrence and the trial was conducted with intention to treat). Actually, i would like more comments on the R code!

Comment: Rather than attempting cbind with three vectors it might have been possible to use: `data[, c("time_meta","time_death","time_loc")]` assuming that all of them were numeric. If they were not all numeric then take two giant steps back and learn that `apply` coerces all lines of its input to be of the came class, because it only works on matrices. You _should_ have at the very least have provided results of `str(data)`

Comment: Please focus one clearly defined task, and ask a specific question about how to accomplish that task, with sample data and examples of the code you have tried.